# filter an object in jquery

Tags: jquery, object, filter

I have an object which I have created as follows:

```
$(this).find('li').each(function(){
                var $itm = $(this);
                localproducts.push({
                    'dataid' : $itm.attr('data-id'), 
                    'datapackage' : $itm.attr('data-package'), 
                    'packageid' : ($itm.children('.packageid').text())
            });
        });
```

now I want to filter the created object localproducts, eg. I want to save all the dataids of items whose packageid is equal to 3 for example. I think it can be done with array filter but not sure how. Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `filter`

```
var matching = $(localproducts).filter(function(){  
    return this.packageid == 3;
});
```

---

using `each`

```
var dataids = new Array();

$(localproducts).each(function(){  
    if (this.packageid == 3) dataids.push(this.dataid);
});
```

---

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/tqTDQ/**

Comment: why jquery? `localproducts.filter(function(){return this.packageid == 3;});`

Comment: thnks but then how do I save the dataids of that result in a variable?

Comment: Lower versions of IE 9 doesn't support native filter method. So jquery may be a good solution.

Comment: it only seems to return 1 result and it returns all the information and not just a list of the dataids

Comment: you can either use `filter` and return the matching elements or use `each` and return only the `dataid` properties

Comment: check my fiddle again. I wasn't matching the `li` properties to what you specified.

Comment: do you mind checking my code here, it doesn-t seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Tcwgf/

Comment: A couple of problems. You weren't using `jQuery`. `catalogue.push(localproducts);` doesn't work like you think it does

Comment: ok thanks I-ve chosen your answer, one last thing how do I save all those returned dataids in a variable? Thanks!

Comment: the `each` version in my answer dumps all of those into the variable `dataids` which is an `Array`

Comment: do you mind explaining why you had to use this code?  catalogue.push(localproducts[localproducts.length - 1]);

Comment: `catalogue.push(localproducts)` does not work like you imagined. What it did was add all items of `localproducts` at index `[0]` of `catalogue`. IE: `catalogue[0][0]`, `catalogue[0][1]`. It is adding the most recently added element of `localproducts` to `catalogue`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **jQuery** `grep` utility.

Here is the URL to the docs:

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.grep

In your case, the code would look something like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr = jQuery.grep(localproducts, function() {
    return localproducts.packageid == 3;
});
```

You can then access the filtered information. It will be inside the array.

Comment: thnks but then how do I save the dataids of that result in a variable?

Comment: they will be in the array (arr.dataid)