# How to filter rows in an jQuery object

Tags: jquery

```
 $target = $('#fruitTable tr').filter(function () {
        var crates = $("#crateTable tr .selected").parent().map(function () {
            return $(this).data("crateid");
        }).get();
        return crates.indexOf($(this).data("crateid")) >= 0;
    });


    // Here I need to filter target based on few checkboxes so,
        var showFresh = $("#cbFreshFruits").prop("checked");
        if (showFresh)
            $target  // how to get fruit tr which has   data-fruitstatus = fresh
```

How can I get rows where data-fruitstatus is fresh,

for example I have rows like this, `<tr data-fruitstatus="Fresh"> Big Mango </tr>`

I find this [filter an object in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340121/filter-an-object-in-jquery) , but I am not sure how to use it for rows(tr) and or if it's best way

Comment: `$target.filter('[data-fruitstatus="Fresh"]')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you add this as a answer please, so I could accept it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and pass an [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as its condition

```
$target.filter('[data-fruitstatus="Fresh"]')
```